# Address of the array vs. address of array[0]- Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, memory-address

In C++ the address of the first element in an array/list is the same as the address of array itself, in the memory. However, when I try the "ID" function in Python to investigate the addresses, I get different IDs for the array[0] and the array itself. Is using ID a correct approach to find the address of the data structure in Python? for example:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4]
print(id(arr))
print(id(arr[0]))
```

I get 17145608 for the id(arr) and 2039216048 for id(arr[0]). the ID are not even close to each other.
Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: `list` objects are not arrays, and `id` gives you the address of the PyObject header. Using `id` this way is nonsensical. It isn't even guaranteed to give you an address, that is a CPython implementation detail. If you read the docs, the only thing `id` does is give oyu an integer guaranteed to be unique for the lifetime of the object. The fact that it is the address of the PyObject header should never be relied upon.

Comment: In general, Python is not at all like C/C++. It is a much higher-level language, and the "address" of objects is almost never something useful to think about, or something you would have to know or care about.